# Which page is referring to *all posts by author*?

Tags: template-hierarchy, author-template

I am developing a blog and whenever I press on an author name I get the page with all pages by this author, but this page looks really bad.

Any ideas of where I should inspect for problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer to the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Author_display

however, your problem is caused by a conflict of the `.author` class output by the `body_class()` and this existing style in custom.css:

```
.author {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -3px;
    width: 219px;
    background: #E7ECEF;
    border-right: 1px solid #D6DFDC;
    height: 41px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

check why this style is added there in the first place;
if there is no reason, remove it; 
if there is a good reason, try to change it to:

```
#content .author { ......
```

Comment: How did you get this? Cause you are so right. I was inspecting with firebug for an hour and you found the problem in a minute. How did you do this? :)

Comment: a: seen it before; b: i use firefox web developer add-on; c: although there is a css id #author in the theme, there is possibly no css class .author

Answer (score 0):

please check  **`author.php`** file in your theme folder.

If there is no  **`author.php`** file in your theme folder, you have to edit **`archive.php`** file. The **`archive.php`** file lists all archive posts(including the author posts) in your WP blog.

If there is no **`archive.php`** file in your theme folder, Simply edit the **`index.php`** file.

you can check if the page is author page by **`is_author()`** function.